# How set @page at-rule dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to set `@page{margin-top: dynamic value}`. The value should be retrieved from an input element of type text. The element is named P1_MARGIN_TOP. Can this be done?

Comment: You haven't tagged JavaScript and I can't see how you can possibly do this without JS.

Comment: I didn't know that javaScript is a must. Anyway, I edited the question, and added it. If you downvote the question for that, you can undo it now.

Comment: I don’t ever downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You will need JavaScript to do this.

Here is a simple snippet to set a CSS variable to the value picked up from the input.

You will need to add code to check that the value and the units the user gives are suitable - I would probably do that with two inputs, one of type number and one a select which has just the options you know will work (e.g. 'in', 'cm'...) to avoid the margin being set to something impossible.

```js
const p1MarginTop = document.querySelector('#P1_MARGIN_TOP');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
// NOTE: you will want to check the value of the input to make sure it makes sense in terms of number and units
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  p1MarginTop.style.setProperty('--margintop', p1MarginTop.value);
  alert('--margintop has been set to: ' + p1MarginTop.style.getPropertyValue('--margintop'));
});
```

```css
@page {
  margin-top: var(--margintop);
}
```

```html
<input id="P1_MARGIN_TOP"><button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I am not a professional web developer, but I think CSS runs before JavaScript, right? If yes, then how should this work?
I tried writing the following in an on page load event...
'const p1MarginTop = document.querySelector('#P7_MARGIN_TOP');
p1MarginTop.style.setProperty('--margintop', p1MarginTop.value);'
Then, my CSS was what you wrote...
'@page {
  margin-top: var(--margintop);
}'

Comment: But don't you want to do that not on page load but on the user doing some input? Hence in my code I have a submit button and clicking that triggers the reading of the value and the setting of the variable. I don't at the moment see the sense in doing it when the page is first loaded, you might as well build it in.

Comment: What do you mean with build it in?
I tried assigning the javascript code to **onbeforeprint** body's event attribute...
`const p1MarginTop = document.querySelector('#P7_MARGIN_TOP'); p1MarginTop.style.setProperty('--margintop', p1MarginTop.value);` and added...
`@media print{@page {
  margin-top: var(--margintop);
}
}` to my inline CSS, but it did not work too.

Comment: jQuery has CSS method that enables developers to write CSS properties to objects. For example, `$("#ITEM_NAME").css("height", "50px");`. If I can use it with **@page**, it could solve the problem. But I tried...
`$("@page").css("margin-top", "50mm");` and it did not work. Can I reference **@page** in jQuery?

Comment: User does not enter a value for the field. User enters a value in another page, for example, page 3. The value is inserted into a database column.
P1_MARGIN_TOP is the item that retrieves the value which the user entered, from the database column.
So, P1_MARGIN_TOP(In another page) is rendered with the value.
Is there a method in JavaScript similar to **CSS** jQuery method? If yes, can it be used to set **@page** at-rule?

Comment: P1_MARGIN_TOP is in another page(1), which I need to print with the margins set dynamically.

Comment: This is now beyond me. The question talks about the value being set in an input element, but now we hear of a database and a separate page. Good luck but I can't fathom what you want. Sorry.

Comment: There's nothing to fathom except that the item is rendered with a value. I need to set **@page{margin-top: value** with that value. That's it.
Have you tried your solution? Did it work? I need to know how it should work if CSS executes before JavaScript. If CSS executes first, then **--margintop** variable will be empty, and changing it through JavaScript won't have an effect, right?

Comment: No. When you change the CSS variable in JS it gets changed. If you run my snippet it shows you that it has been changed.

Comment: Yes, of course, it will change. But how CSS read it if it was already executed before change the variable's value?

Comment: I dont understand! When what was executed? Of course you want the user to input the new margin setting before they go to print the thing.

Comment: As far as I am aware, When a page is being rendered, HTML and CSS are applied. Then JavaScript executes. So, your variable will get it's value after...
`@page {
  margin-top: var(--margintop);
}`
was executed. **--margintop** at that time, did not have a value. 
The CSS code won't run again after changing the variable's value. 
Have you tried it?